# How to create an OPTIONAL many-to-many association in data_mapper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper, rubinius, datamapper-1.2

I'm sorry, I can't ask the question better. I want to be able to create a Station and save it into the db, without having to know about the route yet. How do I have to change my models?

```
class Station
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         String, :key => true

  has n, :routes, :through => Resource
end

class Route
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,   Serial, :key => true

  has n, :stations, :through => Resource
end
```

I'm using `rubinius`, `data_mapper 1.2` and `mariadb`.

Comment: You could have `Unknown` route and assign to it all Stations that don't have real Route yet. ANd later, when you get real Route you could reassign those Stations...

Comment: that's a good workaround, thank you! but I think it should be possible to do it directly in datamapper ;)